# Quickest way to access data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am planning the design of a language learning application. I want a TextView to be able to change between about 400 phrases, however I don't want to hardcode this. I want to make something like a text file with all the phrases stored in there. Then I can change the content of the text file without worrying about having to change my code.

What will be the best way to access the phrases? Should I store them all in the SQLite database? Or should I rather create a text file and store it in the app's resources, and then read from there? Should I use a content provider?

Is there another, better solution?

Comment: `Should I store them all in the SQLite database?` It seems to be the best option, to me. `Should I use a content provider?` No, if you don't want to share data with other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ORM libraries like [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) or [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/). It will be simple and also suit your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not worked with either ORMLite or greenDAO before, but I have read up on it. Why would I rather use them instead of just SQLite? What makes it different/better in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

you should go for a file having XML or JSON data inside. Both approach is using "key" - "value" pair concept. If you don't know about them,

1. [XML](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html)
2. [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html)

If your content, doesn't matter in XML or JSON, is true then if you change it with value, you are done with. What you need to maintain is the format only.

#### Proc

- If you have predefined format of your phrases, if you change the file, it will parse automatically.
- No need to maintain

### Option 2

You can go with database. But then you need to do entry of data or you need to have database file to replace it.

#### Cons

- Entry in database is the main thing you need to think about

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read first the official documentation to know which is the better solution for you.

[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Now, in my personal opinion, I would use the internal storage (a file) for that. Simple and easy access to the information.